How is it possible to have charged sources but with source-free Maxwell equations?
We have that a particle with electric charge $e$, can be described by the electromagnetic potential
$$A_{\mu} = - \frac{e}{r}\, dt \,,$$  which satisfies the Maxwell field equations $$\nabla_{\mu} F^{\mu \nu} = 0 \,,$$ where $F_{\mu \nu} = \partial_{\mu}A_{\nu} - \partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}$.
My question is why the correct equations are not those with sources $\nabla_{\mu} F^{\mu \nu} = J^\nu$. Isn't the particle with electric charge $e$ already a source? Then in what cases the 4-current $J^\nu$ is not zero?


why the correct equations are not those with sources $\nabla_{\mu} F^{\mu \nu} = J^\nu$?

They are, if the charge density is not zero in the region of interest of the spacetime, namely, from a mathematical point of view, the domain of the differential equations.
If charge density is zero in the region of interest, the homogeneous equation $\nabla_{\mu} F^{\mu\nu} = 0$ supplied with the proper boundary conditions governs the EM field there. In the latter case of zero charge density (vacuum of electric charge), the EM field can be different from zero if there is some EM forcing at the boundary: this is the case of propagation of EM waves in vacuum; no net charges in the region of interest, and EM waves entering and leaving the domain through its boundary.

In special relativity, here's the definitions of:

4-current: $J^{\mu} = (c\rho, \mathbf{j}) = (c \rho, \rho \mathbf{v}) = \rho_0 U^\mu$, being $U^{\mu}$ the components of the 4-velocity.
4-potential: $A^{\mu} = \left(\frac{\phi}{c}, \mathbf{a} \right)$
EM field tensor $F_{\mu \nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_{\mu}$

and the pair of Maxwell equations
$$\begin{cases}
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{d} = \rho \\
\nabla \times \mathbf{h} - \partial_t \mathbf{d} = \mathbf{j}
\end{cases}$$
can be written as $\partial_{\mu} D^{\mu \nu} = J^{\nu}$, where $D^{\mu \nu}$ are the components of the so-called electric displacement tensor, related to the EM field tensor through polarization.

If you have a point charge, you need to write the volume charge density for a point charge using Dirac's delta, $\rho(t,\mathbf{r}) = e \delta(\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_P(t))$, being $\mathbf{r}_P(t)$ the position of the charge at time $t$.
In your example, as the charge is not moving, its velocity is $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$ so that the components of the 4-current density are $J^{\mu} = (c \rho, \mathbf{0})$.
Here a link of wiki, and here hand-written notes about electromagnetism in special relativity.

That's exactly the problem. For example, a black hole has a net charge, but still no current

@AndreaDiPinto what does this black hole have to do with this?

I'm not an expert in GR, but I won't use anything of what we wrote here for a bh. I'd use it for a charge distribution with negligible mass

@Triatticus it was just an example of an object with net electric charge but no source current

@Aleph12345 an ordinary charged rubber ball at rest also has a net electric charge but no source current. No need for anything weird like a black hole.

@Dale yes, perfect. My question is exactly why it is charged but no source current is present.

Because the charge is not moving. $\vec J=\rho \vec v$ where $\vec J$ is the current density, $\rho$ is the charge density, and $\vec v$ is the velocity. If $\vec v=0$ then $\vec J=0$ even if $\rho \ne 0$

@Aleph12345 I thought it was clear. I'm editing the last part of the answer, the one dealing with the density of your problem

@Dale, but there is always a system of reference wherein the object is moving

@Aleph12345 yes. And in those reference frames there is a current density. But not in the frame where it is at rest. The current density is frame dependent.


My question is why the correct equations are not those with sources ∇μFμν=Jν. Isn't the particle with electric charge e already a source?

They are. Notice that the potential only satisfies the source-free equation for $r\ne 0$. At $r=0$ it diverges. This is because the source is a single point charge at $r=0$. The two equations are the same in this scenario at $r\ne 0$

$\nabla_{\mu} F^{\mu \nu} = J^\nu$ is a differential equation. $F = F(X^{\alpha})$ and $J = J(X^{\alpha})$. If $J\neq 0$ for the coordinate $X^{\alpha}$, the inhomogeneous equation is valid, otherwise it is the homogeneous equation.
